# Yii CException error when logging in

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to log into my Yii application and I have encountered these multiple errors, which occurred when I was editing the user identity. It only happens when I enter the correct login but if I enter an incorrect one it spits out the `You are using the incorrect password` message.
`Unknown authorization item "admin1".` appears at the top of the page.

And then I get this:

[image: yii cexcption]
[image: continued of previous image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to assign role that does not exist for AuthManager

from your error
Yii::app->authManager->assign('admin1', $this->_id)

If you use CPhpAuthManager you can load from file like this
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPhpAuthManager

```
return [
    'admin1' => [
        'type' => CAuthItem::TYPE_ROLE,
        'description' => 'Admin',
        'children' => [
        ],
        'bizRule' => null,
        'data' => null
    ],
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but im still lost ! i thought i had sone this by changing the user identity with this http://pastebin.com/z9H8M0R3 I've had alook and i haveno idea where to put that. I have 4 other roles to put in also.